# Cant get node value in XML, how can I get it?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Im currently using a simple looped XML script from on w3cschools and it works great:

```
 if (p1p2total == 5)
  {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/SearchRequest-12437.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
document.write("<tr><td class='c3c1'>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("key")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td class='c3c2b'>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("priority")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td class='c3c3b'>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("customfields")[0].getElementsByTagName("customfield")

   [0].getAttributeNode("id").textContent);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
}
```

However on my third node value query, customfields, im trying to obtain the textContent of a node with the following path in my xml:

item -> customfields -> customfield id=10080 -> customfieldvalue

How can I get the textContent value of customfieldvalue?  The parent node has to have an attribute of id=10080 because different items have a varying amount of customfield tags that have different childnode ids.

Please help!!!

I only need this to work in FireFox...

---EDIT---

Ok so I figured out that the xpath I will need to use is:

```
    ./customfields/customfield[@id='customfield_10080']/customfieldvalues/customfieldvalue/text()
```

So how can I replace the line

```
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("customfields")[0].getElementsByTagName("customfield")[0].getAttributeNode("id").textContent);
```

to pull the textcontents of the Xpath I provided while remaining in the javascript loop?  I need this to pull this Xpath for each

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned you only have to call

```
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("customfields")[0].getElementsByTagName("customfield").text;
```

Give it a try. There are several ways of reading and parsing XML from javascript. I wouldn't recommend w3schools for learning. Go to the roots, try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt/JavaScript) for the next time ;)

I hope it helps

Comment: That doesnt work.  I need to be able to get the nodevalue from the child of customfield thats named customfieldvalue.  The problem is that I need to specify the customfield node that has the attribute id=100800"

Thanks for pointing me to MDN, im checking out now!!

Comment: still no luck...

would there be a way to use xpath just for the one entry and have it loop properly?

Comment: I added an edit to my original post that includes the xpath to the node im trying to read.  Thanks for your help everyone!